# Scrolling on a div element with protractor

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, protractor

I need to scroll down an element in order to click a checkbox. Basically a user agreement that i have to accept. The checkbox is unclickable until i didn't scroll to the bottom of the div.
This is how my function that checks the checkbox look like:

```
async privacyStatementEnableCheckbox(){
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    await this.privacyStatementTextContent.click();
    let privacyStatementCheckbox = element(by.xpath(AcceptNewInvitationPage.SELECTORS.privacyStatementCheckbox));
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(this.privacyStatementTextContent).perform();
            await browser.sleep(3000);
            await privacyStatementCheckbox.click();
        }

}
```

I use browser.sleep() to see whats happening, and appearently the div is not scrolling. The error i get is:

> WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point xy... another element would bew clicked instead

I assume this is because there is a "hider" element that is ON the checkbox until the user scrolled to the bottom of the div.

I also tried :

```
async privacyStatementEnableCheckbox(){
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    await this.privacyStatementTextContent.click();
    let privacyStatementCheckbox = element(by.xpath(AcceptNewInvitationPage.SELECTORS.privacyStatementCheckbox));
    await browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000)').then(async function(){
       //check if the checkbox is checked or not
        if(await this.privacyStatementCheckboxValue.getAttribute("data-bv-result") !== "VALID"){
            await browser.sleep(3000);
            await privacyStatementCheckbox.click();
        }
}
```

I know there are a lot of topics about scrolling a div here but i couldn't find a solution among them that works for me.
Neither option performed the scroll on the div for me, and i couldnt find much information about how moseMove(element) works.
If anyone could point out what am i doing wrong i would be grateful.
Additional info: Im using chrome, protractor, cucumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it telling protractor to press the end button

```
await this.privacyStatementTextContent.click();
    await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.END).perform();
    await browser.sleep(1000);
    await privacyStatementCheckbox.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is going against E2E testing concept.

But if you are not going to do any assertion about this agreement and checkbox and you just need to move forward to start actual tests you can:

1. Inspect the checkbox before your have 'read' the agreement
2. Inspect it after and find out what property is changing and making it enabled.
3. Change this property by using `browser.executeScript`